# Cannot get selectedItem to textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to get listbox selected item from one form 1 to display on textbox on form 2.

So far it's working partly.

The problem is that it only gets the selectedItem that was selected at the start of the application. If the user selects a new item, it still gets the one that was selected as default.

Form 1 `MainForm`:

```
public MainForm()
{
    public string GetListBoxSelectedItem()
    {
        if (Animallst.SelectedItem != null) //Animallst is the listbox
        {
            return Animallst.SelectedItem.ToString();
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void foodbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FoodRegister foodForm = new FoodRegister();
        foodForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Form 2 `FoodRegister`:

```
public partial class FoodRegister : Form
{
    private RecipeManager m_foodmanager = new RecipeManager();

    public FoodRegister() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainForm main = new MainForm();
        Nametxt.Text = main.GetListBoxSelectedItem();
        //My initializations
        InitializeGUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning `string.Empty` immediately after returning the `SelectedItem`? What is that being used for?

Comment: string text = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines are not at all doing what you want them to do. You're creating an entirely new instance of `MainForm`, which has nothing to do with the original instance. And so `GetListBoxSelectedItem()` doesn't do what you want either.

```
MainForm main = new MainForm();
Nametxt.Text = main.GetListBoxSelectedItem();
```

Instead, pass a reference to the original Form into the second Form:

```
public FoodRegister(MainForm main) 
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Nametxt.Text = main.GetListBoxSelectedItem();
    ...
```

And then call it like this:

```
FoodRegister foodForm = new FoodRegister(this);
foodForm.Show();
```

Comment: Finally! A billion thanks to you for once again helping me. I really appreciate all your help. Thank you!

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could help me with this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528886/adding-collection-to-listbox)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to mention:

1. The line `return string.Empty` is redundant. Because of the line above it, this line becomes unreachable
2. In your `FoodRegister` for, you create a new instance of your main form. This then wipes anything that the main form was holding - i.e. `Animallst.SelectedItem.ToString();`

An easy way to handle this is to set the value to a static variable - that way you won't have to create a new instance of the form to access it.

Main form:

```
public static string GetListBoxSelectedItem()
{
    if (Animallst.SelectedItem != null) //Animallst is the listbox
    {
        return Animallst.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
    else { return string.Empty(); }
}
```

Food Register:

```
public FoodRegister() 
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainForm.GetListBoxSelectedItem();
    //My initializations
    InitializeGUI();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't played with WinForms in awhile but here goes
In Form 2

```
public partial class FoodRegister : Form
{
    private RecipeManager m_foodmanager = new RecipeManager();
    public FoodRegister() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //My initializations
        InitializeGUI();
    }
    public void SetText(string txt)
    {
         Nametxt.Text = txt;
    }
}
```

In Form 1

```
public MainForm()
{
    private readonly FoodRegister foodForm = new FoodRegister();

    private void foodbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foodForm.SetText(Animallst.SelectedItem == null ? "" : Animallst.SelectedItem.ToString());
        foodForm.Show();
    }
}
```

I replaced

```
GetListBoxSelectedItem()
```

with

```
Animallst.SelectedItem == null ? "" : Animallst.SelectedItem.ToString()
```