# Adding collection to listbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to make it so that a user is able to add `name` and `ingredient` to a listbox.

Here is a brief description of the relevant classes:

> `RecipeForm` is the form.
>
> `RecipeManager` is a collection manager class for `Recipe`
>
> `Recipe` is the "content" class where the fields`name` and `ingredients` are
>
> `ListManager`is the generic base class in which the manager class`RecipeManager` inherits from.

I want the user to input the name and ingredients of a `recipe` object.

And then save that object in an object of the `RecipeManager` in the `RecipeForm` class.

The list of `Recipe` objects saved in the collection (`m_foodManager` in the code below) is supposed to be displayed in a listbox in the `RecipeForm`

Here is how I tried it:

The form `FoodRegister`:

```
 public partial class FoodRegister : Form
  {
        private Recipe m_food = new Recipe();
        private RecipeManager m_foodmanager = new RecipeManager();


 public FoodRegister()
     {
            InitializeComponent();
     }

 private void ReadValues()
     {           
            m_food.Name = Nametxt.Text;
            m_food.Ingredients.Add(Ingredienttxt.Text);
     }

 private void UpdateResults()
     {
            ResultListlst.Items.Clear();  //Erase current list

            //Get one elemnet at a time from manager, and call its 
            //ToString method for info - send to listbox
            for (int index = 0; index < m_foodmanager.Count; index++)
          {  
                Recipe recipe = m_foodmanager.GetAt(index);
                //Adds to the list.
                ResultListlst.Items.Add(recipe);
          }
     }

    private void Addbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
            Recipe recept = new Recipe();

            m_foodmanager.Add(recept);

            ReadValues();
            MessageBox.Show(m_food.Ingredients.ToString());
            UpdateResults();
     }
}
```

`Recipe` class

```
public class Recipe
    {
        private ListManager<string> m_ingredients = new ListManager<string>();
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public ListManager<string> Ingredients
        {
            get { return m_ingredients; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}  {1}",this.Name, this.Ingredients);
        }
    }
```

The `RecipeManager`class (This one is empty because it inherits its methods from `ListManager`.:

```
 public class RecipeManager : ListManager<Recipe>
    {
        public RecipeManager()
        {
        }
    }
```

The `ListManager` class:

```
  public class ListManager<T> : IListManager<T>
    {
        protected List<T> m_list;

        public ListManager()
        {
            m_list = new List<T>();
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return m_list.Count; }
        }

        public  void Add(T aType)
        {
            m_list.Add(aType);
        }

        public void DeleteAt(int anIndex)
        {
            m_list.RemoveAt(anIndex);
        }

        public bool CheckIndex(int index)
        {
            return ((index >= 0) && (index < m_list.Count));
        }
  
        public T GetAt(int anIndex)
        {
            if (CheckIndex(anIndex))
                return m_list[anIndex];
            else 
                return default(T);
        }
    }
```

**The problem** is that when I'm clicking the Add button after inputting the name and ingredients, the listbox displays:

> [namespace].ListManager`1[System.String]

Comment: What's `ResultListlst`? And what API is this? WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET?

Comment: `ResultListlst` is the listbox. This is Windows forms Application

Answer (score 1):

```
Recipe recept = new Recipe();
m_foodmanager.Add(recept);
```

Your recept Object has no value.

My solution:

-In Recipe class: Add a constructor to Recipe object

```
public Recipe(string name){
this.name = name;
}
```

-In RecipeManager class: add method:

```
public List<Recipe> AddList(Recipe r){
return m_list;
}
```

and change "T" to "Recipe" object.

-In FoodRegister class: Add code to method

```
private void Addbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
Recipe rc = new Recipe(Nametxt.Text);
ListManager lm = new ListManager();
lm.Add(rc);
for (int index = 0; index < lm.Count; index++)
      {  
            Recipe recipe = lm.GetAt(index);
            ResultListlst.Items.Add(recipe.Name);
      }
}
```

Hope that's useful.
Let me know when it's done.

Comment: It partly worked. It only displays the name. I want it to display the ingredient too. Thank you

Comment: Very simple: define one more variable for Recipe Object
And add this to listbox:
ResultListlst.Items.Add(recipe.Name + " " + recipe.Ingredient);
Hope that's useful.

Comment: I tried, but I don't know how to assign the list `ListManager<string>` to textbox. Can you show example in code, please.

Comment: If you want to show both Name and Ingredient, your ListManager<string> cannot do that. Because you need to show 2 strings while your list has only 1. So my Solution is that you change your ListManager<string> to ListManager<Recipe>.

Comment: How would it help if I changed `ListManager<string>` to `ListManager<Recipe>`?

The problem is that I don't know how to assign the ingredient textbox to the` ListManager<string>`

Comment: your ListManager<string> contains Name or Ingredient attribute only. If you want it to contain both, change to ListManager<Recipe>. I recode the solution. Hope that's useful.

Comment: I want to display ingredient only. Do I need to change the ListManager to <Recipe>?

Answer (score 1):

Recipe class

```
private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

private string ingredient;
    public string Ingredient
    {
        get { return ingredient; }
        set { ingredient = value; }
    }
public Recipe(string name, string ingredient){
this.name = name; 
this.ingredient = ingredient;
}
```

ListManager class:

```
//define a list that contains Recipe Object
private List<Recipe> reList ;

public ListManager(){
reList = new List<recipe>();
}

//add your methods Add, GetAt and Count... here.
```

FoodRegister class

```
public partial class FoodRegister : Form
{
ListManager<Recipe> lm;

public FoodRegister()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   lm = new ListManager<Recipe>();
}

private void UpdateResults()
 {
        ResultListlst.Items.Clear();  //Erase current list
        for (int index = 0; index < lm.Count; index++)
      {  
            Recipe recipe = lm.GetAt(index);
            ResultListlst.Items.Add(recipe.Name + " " + recipe.Ingredient);
      }
 }

private void Addbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        Recipe recept = new Recipe(txtName.Text, txtIngredient.Text);
        lm.Add(recept);          
        UpdateResults();
 }
```

Comment: And if I only wan to display ingredient?

Comment: ListManager contains your Recipe object (Name, Ingredient or sth more).
ListBox is to display what u want to show. So, your question is only display ingredient, my answer is NO change Recipe Object. You change your ListBox code: ResultListlst.Items.Add(recipe.Ingredient);

Answer (score 0):

You need implement ToString() for ListManager

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(",",this.m_list.ToArray());
    }
```