# How to save an object in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I have created a program and in one form i created an array that saves textbox-strings. Now i want to create another array that holds that array, a name, desciption and a category. I'm not supposed to use list, I think. Well the problem for med is to save the object in the second array.

```
    private const int maxNumOfElements = 50;
    private myClass[] theList = new myClass[maxNumOfElements];
```

Comment: You want to use a class, not an array.

Comment: You are storing empty `strings` in that array..?

Comment: *"I'm not supposed to use list"* ... is this a school homework exercise?

Answer (score 1):

Although this appears to be homework, I was once where you are.  Here is a full example in a c# winforms app, if I understand your requirement correctly:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        string[] test = new string[] { "Test Name","Test Description","Test Category"};
        MyClass oClass = new MyClass();
        oClass.MyArray = test;

        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + oClass.MyName + Environment.NewLine +
            "Description: " + oClass.MyDescription + Environment.NewLine +
            "Category: " + oClass.MyCategory);
    }
}
 class MyClass
{
    private string _myName;

    public string MyName
    {
        get { return _myName; }
        set { _myName = value; }
    }

    private string _myDesc;

    public string MyDescription
    {
        get { return _myDesc; }
        set { _myDesc = value; }
    }
    private string _myCat;

    public string MyCategory
    {
        get { return _myCat; }
        set { _myCat = value; }
    }
    private string[] _myArr;

    public string[] MyArray
    {
        get { return _myArr; }
        set {
            _myArr = value;
            MyName = value[0];
            MyDescription = value[1];
            MyCategory = value[2];
        }
    }


}
```

}

output

Name: Test Name

Description: Test Description

Category: Test Category

Comment: Thank you for respondidng, but my problem was to add that other array to my array. It's a windows forms application but it doesnt matter. Or am i supposed to use a jagged array which hold other arrays?                                                        private const int maxNumOfElements = 50;
private Class[] theList = new Class[maxNumOfElements];                          this is the array I want to save.

Comment: Ok let me clarify, I'll update the answer.  So you have Array1, and you need to copy it into Array2 only?  Sorry, the "not supposed to use a list" comment confused me initially.  Can you clarify, the "create another array that holds that array, a name, desciption and a category" part?  That looks to me like it's asking for a class, not an array.

Comment: Sorry, "You want to use a class, not an array." – Abion47. Guess that's what I'm trying to say. Array of objects.

Comment: Ok, before I rework this, just to make sure.  You're wanting a starting array  (I'll call it Array1) with 3 objects, Name, Description, and Category.  With this array, you want to create a second array (Array2) containing Name, Description, Category, and Array1?

Comment: nevermind, sorry for wasting your time, I will just fail this assignment.

Comment: Nah don't give up.  This is called requirements gathering.  It's a huge step in your future career...  We just need to get to where I understand what you need clearly, and I'll help you out.  Don't lose hope, we'll get it..  Tell me what inputs you have, and what outputs you want for starters... Input is an array, output is an array, correct?

Comment: If you have an array of reference types, i.e. objects, you create the array first and then create each element of the array.  For instance, if you have array of Recipes (as in the RecipeManager), to add a Recipe object in the array or save one at any position, the Recipeobject must have been created using the keyword new, in addition to that the array itself is created:
o Create the array:  private Recipe[] recipeArray = new Recipe[maxItems];o recipeArray[index] = new Recipe(maxIngredients);

Comment: Ok, I think that was enough to get us there.  Take a look at this question, see if the answer also answers yours.  I'll check back to see if you need further help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528886/adding-collection-to-listbox

Comment: I guess its the same assignment, however he is using a list and his question isnt answered. Did you understand "array of reference" which was describred above? ^^